# Converting Bitmap to Binary Array performance

Tags: c#, performance, bitmap, memorystream

I do have a Bitmap Array that contains more than 500 Bitmaps object. I need to convert each single Bitmap object within the Array into a binary Array. I'm using the MemoryStream class to achieve this:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
    images[0].Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    byte[] byteData = ms.ToArray();
}
```

I would like to know if there is other way to achieve this. I'm not sure how expensive is this process.

Thanks

Comment: Well if you don't know how long that takes, how should we..

Comment: Thanks Blindy, I just looking for the best way to achive this, I'm not sure how expensive is using MemoryStreams

Comment: That seems like a perfectly valid approach to me. Depending on what format you choose (gif, png, etc), you'll get different size arrays (depends on how much compression a given format has)

Comment: In general memory streams are very fast simply because they reside in memory. I'd argue if you're not seeing any performance issues, stick with this approach. Always profile and verify this really is your bottleneck if you are seeing issues.

Comment: Indeed, as long as you have to convert in-memory 500+ bitmaps at runtime, that's your best bet really. Try PNG's instead of GIF's and compare the two, but otherwise you're set. I would however suggest perhaps caching these converted images on disk and only regenerating them if the sources change or something.

Comment: Thanks for your kind responses.That makes more sense for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some speed tests and converting to ImageFormat.Bmp is the fastest. It doesn't need to do any compression. Though the best format will also depend on what you plan to do with the data after that.

It's also worth considering where the Bitmaps came from in the first place. If you're loading them in from a file it may be worth it to switch things around and read the file data in first, then create your Bitmap objects from it after that.

Answer (score 1):

By choosing Gif you are making a CPU/memory trade off which you most likely don't want.  Specifically the Gif is going to be smaller but is going to take some time to compress (unless the images are already in the format) relative to using a BMP.

If you are copying these around enough that you have memory bandwidth issues (and can't fix that) this is a good idea, but otherwise you should stick with BMP.  Really though, for 500 images I would expect this to take 1-2 seconds at the most so you probably don't need to worry about this sort of micro optimization.  If its taking to long you can move to unmanaged code which will likely perform better because you will have finer control over memory allocations and copies.

Comment: Thanks, It was useful.The process I'm using is suppose to extract images from a PDF File, but I don't want to save those images to disk, instead, I save it to a MemoryStream and then show the image up in a UI.